# GWT Incubator ERROR

Tags: gwt

The application works well if I debug from Eclipse but when I try to compile I get this:

```
Compiling module org.uk.xxx.web.stuff
   Validating newly compiled units
      [WARN] Warnings in 'jar:file:/C:/javacvs/gwt-incubator-20101117-r1766.jar!/com/google/gwt/widgetideas/client/impl/GlassPanelImpl.java'
         [WARN] Line 30: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.DocumentRootImpl'
         [WARN] Line 38: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.DocumentRootImpl'
      [WARN] Warnings in 'jar:file:/C:/javacvs/gwt-incubator-20101117-r1766.jar!/com/google/gwt/widgetideas/table/client/FixedWidthGridBulkRenderer.java'
         [WARN] Line 122: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.widgetideas.table.client.overrides.HTMLTable'
      [WARN] Warnings in 'jar:file:/C:/javacvs/gwt-incubator-20101117-r1766.jar!/com/google/gwt/widgetideas/table/client/GridBulkRenderer.java'
         [WARN] Line 102: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.widgetideas.table.client.overrides.HTMLTable'
         [WARN] Line 103: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.widgetideas.table.client.overrides.Grid'
         [WARN] Line 104: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.widgetideas.table.client.overrides.Grid'
         [WARN] Line 104: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.widgetideas.table.client.overrides.HTMLTable'
      [WARN] Warnings in 'jar:file:/C:/javacvs/gwt-incubator-20101117-r1766.jar!/com/google/gwt/widgetideas/table/client/TableBulkRenderer.java'
         [WARN] Line 404: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.widgetideas.table.client.overrides.HTMLTable'
   [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/javacvs/gwt-incubator-20101117-r1766.jar!/com/google/gwt/gen2/widgetbase/client/Gen2CssInjector.java'
      [ERROR]  Internal compiler error
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JClassType, but class was expected
    at com.google.gwt.libideas.resources.rebind.context.AbstractResourceBundleGenerator.generate(AbstractResourceBundleGenerator.java:142)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorExtWrapper.generate(GeneratorExtWrapper.java:48)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorExtWrapper.generateIncrementally(GeneratorExtWrapper.java:60)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:662)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:41)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:74)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:259)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.getAllPossibleRebindAnswers(DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.doFindAdditionalTypesUsingRebinds(WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.java:106)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.process(AbstractCompiler.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:444)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:175)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:288)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.access$400(AbstractCompiler.java:145)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:632)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.BasicWebModeCompiler.getCompilationUnitDeclarations(BasicWebModeCompiler.java:124)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.getCompilationUnitDeclarations(WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.java:54)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:517)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:35)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:541)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:495)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:407)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:215)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:187)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:159)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:87)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:81)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:166)

[ERROR] Unexpected
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JClassType, but class was expected
    at com.google.gwt.libideas.resources.rebind.context.AbstractResourceBundleGenerator.generate(AbstractResourceBundleGenerator.java:142)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorExtWrapper.generate(GeneratorExtWrapper.java:48)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorExtWrapper.generateIncrementally(GeneratorExtWrapper.java:60)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:662)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:41)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:74)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:259)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.getAllPossibleRebindAnswers(DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.doFindAdditionalTypesUsingRebinds(WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.java:106)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.process(AbstractCompiler.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:444)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:175)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:288)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.access$400(AbstractCompiler.java:145)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:632)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.BasicWebModeCompiler.getCompilationUnitDeclarations(BasicWebModeCompiler.java:124)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.getCompilationUnitDeclarations(WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.java:54)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:517)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:35)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:541)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:495)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:407)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:215)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:187)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:159)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:87)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:81)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:166)
```

Any help would be fine.

Comment: Seems I have to get an older version of GWT to use this version of incubator!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a GWT 2.2 problem, The classes in the `com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo` package are converted to interfaces, which results in this error for jar file's in your project that use theses classes.

The solution is to get an updated version of the library, or checkout the sources and build the library, or if both options are not available you can modify the bytecode in the jar as described at this site: http://grack.com/blog/2011/03/03/gwt-2-2-and-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror/

Comment: I found a new build of the incubator which solved my issue.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Incubator for GWT 2.2](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/issues/detail?id=381)

fixed :)